# Access 2007 query to capture records that encompass 2 dates

Tags: ms-access, date, ms-access-2007

I'm working on a query to get records based on two dates, start and end dates.

What I need to obtain are records that are span some or all of the given period, in other words the start date maybe before the parameter date but less than the end date or start after the start date and end after the end date.

I.e. Start date = 01 Oct 12 and end date 31 Oct 12. I would like to capture records where start date is before 1 Oct but spans this period whether it finishes in November or mid October. As well as records that are between 01 Oct 12 and 31 Oct 12.

In reality I need the records that exclude this period, but first need to make sure I'm getting this dataset correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm starting with this simple data set stored in `MyTable`, with both `start_date` and `end_date` as Date/Time data type.

```
id start_date end_date
 1  9/29/2012 9/30/2012
 2  9/29/2012 10/2/2012
 3  9/29/2012 11/1/2012
 4  10/2/2012 11/1/2012
 5  11/1/2012 11/2/2012
```

Running the query below, and supplying `2012-10-01` and `2012-10-31` for the `range_start` and `range_end` parameters, gives me this output result set.

```
id start_date end_date
 2  9/29/2012 10/2/2012
 3  9/29/2012 11/1/2012
 4  10/2/2012 11/1/2012
```

If this is not similar to what you wanted, please edit your question to show us a brief sample set of input data and the output you want from that sample.

Also, note the time components of my `start_date` and `end_date` values were all midnight.  If your counterparts include any other times of day, you will need to revise the query to deal with them.

This is the SQL from the query I used:

```
PARAMETERS range_start DateTime, range_end DateTime;
SELECT m.id, m.start_date, m.end_date
FROM MyTable AS m
WHERE
       m.start_date Between [range_start] And [range_end]
    OR m.end_date Between [range_start] And [range_end]
    OR (m.start_date<[range_start] AND m.end_date>[range_end]);
```